# Windows 10 - Force shutdown nightly

Tags: windows-10

I'd like to make sure my pc turns off nightly but not if I'm using when its designated to shut down. I'd like a prompt asking if I'd like to continue the shutdown. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `shutdown /s /t 60` to the task manager that will be fired up on specified time. If you want to be asked before shutdown, write some simple VBS script that throw a warning message that says that computer will be turned off in 60 seconds. If you want to cancel shutdown, issue `shutdown /a` command.

Keep in mind that windows can wake up your computer when microsoft may decide to do some update (in power management from control panel you can restrict it a little bit by disabling such behavior by disabling "wake up timers").